# Testing: Logs: Only showing last 200/300 lines, how to see full logs

Tags: aws-lambda

I am using AWS lambda. Trying to test my code first.

I am doing some heavy printing.

I see the logs are truncated. Looks like only last 300+ lines are shown

Any way I can see all the print lines

[image]

Comment: I recommend you to check the log in CloudWatch Log, make sure you have `Configuration > Monitoring and operations tools > Logs and metrics > Enabled` then go to `Monitor > View CloudWatch logs`

Comment: there also its truncated.

Comment: Go to the CloudWatch console to see the complete logs. Lambda automatically integrates with CloudWatch Logs and pushes all logs from your code to a CloudWatch Logs group associated with a Lambda function named `/aws/lambda/<function name>`. You can see the targeted logs group name and stream name in the execution result screenshot you have shared .

Comment: Impossible, you don't know how to use it only.

Comment: its  here. sorry.